# VBox .getHeight() Not Changing until after .setOnAction Finishes

Tags: javafx

So I'm not sure how to calculate the height of the node during the .setOnAction event I have tried `.requestLayout()`/`.applyCss()` not sure what else to try I am trying to find the height of the vBox after adding a node but it is only printing the height of the node before the new one was added

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox vBoxContainer = new VBox();
        vBoxContainer.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBoxContainer.setPrefSize(200,200);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("newLabel"));
        vBoxContainer.getChildren().add(vBox);

        Button button = new Button("Add Label");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Height Before new Label:"+vBox.getHeight());
            vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("newLabel"));
            //here is where I was adding code to produce expected result
            System.out.println("Height After new Label:"+vBox.getHeight());
        });

        Button checkButton = new Button("Print VBox Height");
        checkButton.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("VBox Height:"+vBox.getHeight()));

        vBoxContainer.getChildren().addAll(button, checkButton);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBoxContainer));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Run the example and Click the button that adds a Label to the vBox and it outputs

Actual Result:

```
Height Before new Label:85.0
Height After new Label:85.0
```

Expected Result:

```
Height Before new Label:85.0
Height After new Label:102.0
```

But if you then click the Print VBox Height Button it will show the correct height of:

```
VBox Height:102.0
```

Comment: Trying adding a listener to the VBox's height property and updated your height from there.

Comment: So in my actual program I need to run more code based off of the new height would I use the listener to update a variable and use that variable in the rest of the setOnAction?

Comment: Sounds like you just need an `if-statement` in the listener.

Comment: Yea, set a variable with greater scope in the listener if you need it to be current when you press some other button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding a listener to the `VBox's` height property.

```
VBox vBoxContainer = new VBox();
vBoxContainer.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
vBoxContainer.setPrefSize(200, 200);

VBox vBox = new VBox();
vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
vBoxContainer.getChildren().add(vBox);
vBox.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("Height changed to: " + newValue.doubleValue());
    if(newValue.doubleValue() > 100)
    {
        //do something!
    }
});
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("newLabel"));
}
Button button = new Button("Add Label");
button.setOnAction(event -> {
    vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("newLabel"));
});
Button checkButton = new Button("Print VBox Height");
checkButton.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("VBox Height:" + vBox.getHeight()));

vBoxContainer.getChildren().addAll(button, checkButton);
stage.setScene(new Scene(vBoxContainer));
stage.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

`requestLayout` does not actually do a layout pass. It simply tells JavaFX, that a layout pass is required which will result in JavaFX doing the layout pass some time *after* your method returns. To do the layout yourself, you need to call `layout` yourself, i.e. change the logic in the event handler like this:

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {
    System.out.println("Height Before new Label:"+vBox.getHeight());
    vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("newLabel"));

    // manually doing layout on the root here
    vBoxContainer.applyCss();
    vBoxContainer.layout();

    System.out.println("Height After new Label:"+vBox.getHeight());
});
```

Note that I do the layout pass for the root, since the ancestor layouts can also be involved in determining the actual size of a `Node`...